# bold in theorem

Tags: bold, greek

I'd like to know why the "Theorem", "Lemma", etc are not in bold in my text. The code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs,enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textcolor{black}{$\blacksquare$}}
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

...

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\en}[1]{%
  \foreignlanguage{english}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\eng}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\newcommand{\eeng}{\end{otherlanguage}}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Ορισμός}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prp}[thm]{Πρόταση}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Λήμμα}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{px}[thm]{Παράδειγμα}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{col}[thm]{Πόρισμα}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{note}[thm]{Παρατήρηση}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{prf}[thm]{Απόδειξη}
\theoremstyle{remark}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fonts provided by `fourier` don't have support for Greek.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Do you know what package should I import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fourier` fonts don't support Greek, so you get warnings about font substitutions.

An available Greek font that's similar to Utopia is GFS Artemisia.

If you add

```
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}
```

to your preamble, you get, from

```
\begin{thm}
\en{Theorem} Theorem % just for comparison
$\alpha\beta$ ab
\end{thm}
```

the output

[image]

Other possible choices are, instead of `\usepackage{fourier}`,

```
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

which will use a Times-like font. Here `\substitutefont` is not necessary.

**Note.** It's not necessary to repeat `\theoremstyle` declarations. The scope of one lasts until countermanded by another similar declaration.